# I want to add custom UIButton to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

In customCell I create some UIButtons and [self addSubview:button];
In UITableView [button addTarget:action:forControlEvents:],When I click button in cell indexPath.row = 0,the indexPath.row = 11 was clicked;
How to get clicked the button and other buttons are not affected?

```
enter code here

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
         (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    SettingTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[SettingTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                  reuseIdentifier:identifier]autorelease];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        [cell.customBtn setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if(indexPath.section == 1){

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [cell.customBtn setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 1){
        [cell.customBtn setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else{
        [cell.customBtn setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2){
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [cell.customBtn setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else {
            [cell.customBtn setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
    [cell.WIFIButton addTarget:self action:@selector(openOrCloseButtonClick:) 
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 7;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 1) {
        return 3;
    }
    else if(section == 2){
        return 2;
    }
    else if(section == 6){
        return 4;
    } 
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}


enter code here
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        CGFloat originX = IsIOS7?10:15;
        UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(originX, 7, 150, 30)];
        nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        nameLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
        nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.nameLabel = nameLabel;
        [self addSubview:nameLabel];
        [nameLabel release];
        CGFloat rightX = IsIOS7?180:160;
        UILabel *fileSizeLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rightX - 10, 10, 100,  
                                                                            25)];
        fileSizeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        fileSizeLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        fileSizeLabel.hidden = YES;
        self.fileSizeLabel = fileSizeLabel;
        [self addSubview:fileSizeLabel];
        [fileSizeLabel release];
        //This is customButton
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(rightX, 10, 50, 25);
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        self.WIFIButton = button;
        [self addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: You didn't post enough code to get a good answer, but I'll take a guess: you are setting the button tag = indexPath.row when it's created.  The cell gets reused and the very same cell (and button it contains) appears at a different row, click that one and it has the wrong tag.  Post your button creation code so I can confirm and supply an answer.

Comment: I'll break out my crystal ball and bet that danh is going to use the words -prepareForReuse in his eventual response...

Comment: Code has been uploaded!Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure, but we need to see the code where customBtn is created/added to the cell.  Also, the addTarget for that button and the method that it invokes.

Comment: Why you did not add action for every button into the **customcell** file. It'll easy to monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jumping the gun a little on the code, but please consider the following.  Add a method that can find the cell where a view appears without using tags.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathOfSubview:(UIView *)view {
    while (view && ![view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell self]]) {
        view = view.superview;
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)view;
    return [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```

This assumes you have an outlet called tableView pointing to a table (and it assumes that the parameter is a subview of one of the table's cells).  Now, on whatever method runs when a button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)myButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self indexPathOfSubview:sender];
    NSLog(@"button pressed in section %d, at row %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
    // ta-da!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change static to dynamic cell

```
static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
```

to

```
NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d",indexPath.row];
```

may be its working

Comment: Thank you very much! NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d",indexPath.row]; I can not reuse.